# SolR index size had reduced alone

Tags: solr

This morning the index size on our SolR Cloud 7.5 shows a 10%+ reduction.

We have not performed any `optimize` and the merge count is flat (so it's not TMP)...

Just to know what happend, have some clue ?

EDIT: it's related to deleted docs being expunged, but metrics does not report any merge or expunge or optimize...

I'm monitoring `UPDATE.updateHandler.merges` for the relevant collection. So it maybe TMP but can't monitor merge activity :(

Comment: Physically on disk or in the number of documents? What about timestamps on the index files? How about old segments being kept open, but as new searches replaced the old ones, old files were free'd up?

Comment: the index size given by solr metrics api. not physically

Comment: @MatsLindh it's linked with delete expunge (deleted docs dropped out) but I cannot monitor any merge/expunge activity in the meantime